# Sublime Text 2: How to change tab font for the soda theme?

Tags: sublimetext2

The tab font in sublime, for the Soda Theme are too small on my screen.

I added a font.size element to the appropriate file, which made the font larger (more detail below), but the viewing area hasn't grown with the font. How do I fix this?

[image]

As you can see, I also tried the margins of tabset_control.

---

Where I added the font.size element:

I added `"font.size": 15.0` to C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Soda\Soda Dark.sublime-theme, around line 189 for me:

```
//
// TAB LABELS
//

{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "fade": true,
    "fg": [170, 170, 170],
    "shadow_color": [25, 25, 25],
    "shadow_offset": [0, -1],
    "tab_height": 50,
    "font.size": 15.0
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug, still hasn't been fixed.
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8889

Answer (score 3):

Keep the location of `font.size` the same, and change the `tab_height` in the `Tab set` section at the beginning of the `.sublime-theme` file:

```
 // Tab set
    {
        "class": "tabset_control",
        "layer0.texture": "Theme - Soda/Soda Dark/tabset-background.png",
        "layer0.inner_margin": [1, 7],
        "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
        "content_margin": [-4, 0, -4, 3],
        "tab_overlap": 5,
        "tab_width": 180,
        "tab_min_width": 45,
        "tab_height": 25,
        "mouse_wheel_switch": false

    },
```

Comment: the `tab_height` in the `tabset_control` only makes all the tabs heigher but not the font in the tab, the text area is still very limited as the pics shown above.